# Should I add a custom backend to my Next.js project?

Tags: javascript, express, next.js

**I have a fully-running express backend from my previous project.** Having created a new Next.js project, now I have to make a critical decision: adding my express backend or use Next.js's default server.(with directory based routing). After reading [Next.js doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) and some other resources, I am comparing the pros and cons of each (some questions emerged too):

> A) If I add my custom express server

1. ✓ Availability of wide range of packages/libraries
2. ✓ Easy usage of middlewares (no customization needed)
3. ✘ Lose 'Automatic Static Optimization'( I didn't understand)
4. ✘ Problems with SSR / SSG ( -? I am not sure)
5. ✘ Lose directory based routing (this is ok)
6. ✘ Unable to host on vercel (this is ok)

> B) If I keep default Next.js server

1. ✓ Host on vercel
2. ✓ Automatic Static Optimization ( I didn't understand)
3. ✘ I have to transform the routing system to directory based approach
4. ✘ Some packages stop working or need replacemant
5. ✘ Need to create a custom middleware handler

Which one should I do? I want a well-explained answer from someone who tried both ways. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your existing express application serves with some sort of API – RESTful, GraphQL, etc.

In my own experience, I had API and entire business logic live in the express application, including model layer, data layer, etc. Naturally, I had a lot of dependencies (like express itself, mongo, bcrypt, etc.)

What I noticed with Next.js is that it would automatically bundle those dependencies in the bundle that is served to the front-end.

- It obviously increases bundle size
- But also brings some dependencies that are not compatible with the browser environment

There is obviously a hack that allows filtering which packages end up in front-end bundle, however, naturally it's a hack that you'd need to maintain as the project grows. Also, we were not necessarily thrilled with directory based routing for the API.

In my project, we decided to keep the express app separate from Next.js app in a monorepo. Effectively, Next.js app would only fetch some data (for SSR) from the API and render it as needed, but Next.js did not have any BE logic except simple fetch calls.

Keeping two separate apps also requires certain maintenance; in our environment, we used Docker and hardened nginx to route requests between API and FE code. Essentially all calls to `/api/` were routed to express app.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this info "What I noticed with Next.js is that it would automatically bundle those dependencies in the bundle that is served to the front-end".

Comment: @GabrielLinassi there are several caveats that I noticed. For example, barrel files would automatically bundle everything even if some files are not used on FE.